# Span are being fored to be displayed as block

Tags: position, html, css

I have some `<span>`s inside a `<div>` which is positioned `absolute`.

```
<div class="post">
<div class="post-main">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class='post-meta'>
        <div> <!-- These 2 spans are supposed to be displayed in ONE line -->
            <span class='post-meta-key'>Field#1</span>
            <span class='post-meta-value'>5-3</span>
            </div>
        <div>...
```

```
.post {position:relative;}
.post-main {position: absolute; left:80%; top:80%;}
```

This should work as I want but the spans are collapsing into new lines. Why? What would be a fix?

Comment: Post more of your CSS, or better yet, create a jsfiddle for us ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
span {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline` is the default for `span` tag